# Greedy vs Non-Greedy in Perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl

Here is the line of text I'm trying to perform a regex on:

```
"MATS"?"Base Revenue Element"?#Mi?#Mi
```

Here is my regex:

```
s/\?[^"]/FOUND/;
```

I expect to get:

```
"MATS"?"Base Revenue Element"?FOUNDMi?FOUNDMi
```

But instead I get:

```
"MATS"?"Base Revenue Element"?FOUNDMi?#Mi
```

So I switched it to:

```
s/\?[^"]?/FOUND/;
```

But now I get:

```
"MATS"FOUND"Base Revenue Element"?#Mi?#Mi
```

So:

1. Why does it only perform one find and then stop in the line of text?
2. Why does adding the non-greedy ? make it find the first question mark even though it's next to a double quote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Because `s///` only does one replacement by default. You use the `g` modifier to make it do as many as possible: `s/\?[^"]/FOUND/g;`
2. Because `?` isn't the "non-greedy modifier" following an atom, it's the "zero or one" quantifier. `\?[^"]?` matches a question mark *optionally* followed by a non-quote character; it will match "?" alone if it's followed by a quote. Greediness actually has nothing to do with what's going on here.